# partition an external usb hard drive

Tags: mac, partitioning

I want to partition this hard drive, so that i can have around 200GB formatted in FAT16, so i can read and write it on Windows.

Is this possible? How?

[image: from get info]

[image]

Comment: According to [this Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) maximum volume size for FAT16 is 32 MiB. It's 2 GiB for FAT16B -- still about 100 times too low for your 200 GB. Isn't this [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? Your real issue seems to be "how to make 200 GB partition usable both on Windows and Mac?"

Comment: thank you for the info and yes, it appears to be also a XY problem, sorry for that. However, the main problem here is that the "partition" button here is disabled from the start

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez _“the main problem here is that the "partition" button here is disabled from the start”_ You cannot partition a partition… Select the disk in the sidebar instead. Or use the Erase button to format the current partition if you do not need to resize partitions.

Comment: @Melebius when i select the disk, the partition button is also disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Select `MS-DOS (FAT)` format type and it would be compatible with MAC and Windows as well.

The FAT is an ideal file system to use for USB flash drives or external hard drives that are intended for use in environments with multiple operating systems.

The primary downside to using FAT is the size limit. You can override that problem by using `exFAT`, though you will lose some compatibility with older versions of Mac OS X and Windows.

**Solution 2:**

The NTFS file system is another option to use for Windows formatted drives and volumes, but it has limited compatibility with Mac OS by default. Mac users can mount and read NTFS formatted Windows drives, making NTFS compatible with the Mac on the reading and mounting front, but writing to an NTFS drive requires third party software or [enabling NTFS write support on the Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x).

This is less than ideal for most users however, so while NTFS is compatible with a Mac and Windows PC, if you want to do heavy file sharing between the two with a lot of reading and writing, you may be better off formatting a drive as FAT as discussed above.

**Remember**, formatting a drive erases all data on it.

Comment: Also, formatting a partition as NTFS pretty much must be done from the Windows side. exFAT is probably a better choice as it's designed to be portable.